# substring to retrieve a date between two characters

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

Could someone shed some light on how I could extract the date field from this string below

```
'NA,Planning-Completed=17-07-2019 10:38,Print-Dispatch-Date=10-02-2020 13:06,Award-Complete=NA'
```

Expected Output:

```
10-02-2020
```

This is what I have written so far, it seems to work sometimes but I noticed some rows are incorrect.

```
[Dispatch Date] = SUBSTRING(dates,CHARINDEX('Print-Dispatch-Date=',dates) + LEN('Print-Dispatch-Date='), LEN(dates) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd parameter for `SUBSTRING` is wrong. You have it as `LEN(dates)`, which means return every character ***after*** `'Print-Dispatch-Date='`; in this case that returns `'10-02-2020 13:06,Award-Complete=NA'`.

As your date is 10 characters long, just use `10`:

```
SELECT dates, SUBSTRING(dates,CHARINDEX('Print-Dispatch-Date=',dates) + LEN('Print-Dispatch-Date='), 10)
FROM (VALUES('NA,Planning-Completed=17-07-2019 10:38,Print-Dispatch-Date=10-02-2020 13:06,Award-Complete=NA'))V(dates)
```